# Outlook addin - Save meeting event

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

I'm creating an addin for outlook 2010 with c# to be used internally at work.

When a user add or update an event in the outlook calendar, i want to send the infos of the event to a database. 
However i can't find an event in the addins that would allow me to do so.

Am I just missing something or there really no event for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Items.ItemAdd / ItemChange events off the MAPIFolder object representing the calendar folder(Namespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)).